# Volume using Triple Integral

Tags: calculus

I would like to find the volume of the solid with

$$2-z \geq x^2+y^2$$ 
$$z^2\geq x^2+y^2$$
$$x^2+y^2 \geq 1/4$$ 
and $x,y,z\geq 0$, using triple integrals. The problem I have is that I don't know which the integral bounds will be. 
Thank you.

Comment: Apart from the problem of finding the bounds, which method do you plan to use ?

Comment: V=$\int \:\int \:\int \:dxdydz$

Comment: Move to Cylindrical Coord...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transfer it to cylindrical coordinate system will make it much  easier:

$x=r\cos{\phi},y=r \sin{\phi},r^2=x^2+y^2 \implies r\ge \dfrac{1}{2},z\ge r,2-z\ge r^2 \implies r\le z \le 2-r^2 \implies r\le 2-r^2 \implies r\le1 \\V=\int \:\int \:\int \:rdrd\phi dz$

you know $x,y \ge 0 $, so you know $\phi$'s range and solve it.